# Random Number between -.5 and .5

Tags: java

I'm trying to get a random number to be generated between -.5 and .5, but I'm running into some errors

```
Rng.java:11: error: ';' expected
    double randomWithRange(double min, double max)
                          ^
Rng.java:11: error: <identifier> expected
    double randomWithRange(double min, double max)
                                      ^
Rng.java:11: error: not a statement
    double randomWithRange(double min, double max)
                                              ^
Rng.java:11: error: ';' expected
    double randomWithRange(double min, double max)
```

and here's the code

```
class Rng
{

double min = -0.5;
double max = 0.5;

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
double randomWithRange(double min, double max)
    {
    double range = (max - min);     
    return (Math.random() * range) + min;
    }


}
}
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Java doesn't allow you to nest a method inside another.  Move `randomWithRange` out of `main`.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that your method `randomWithRange()` is inside your `main()` method, this is not permitted in java.

Try something like that:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    double min = -0.5;
    double max = 0.5;
    System.out.println(randomWithRange(min, max));
}

static double randomWithRange(double min, double max)
{
    double range = (max - min);     
    return (Math.random() * range) + min;
}
```

You may also want to have a look at [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/info) in the **Beginners' resources** section.

Answer (score 4):

You are declaring a method inside another method:

```
public static void main(...) {
  double randomWithRange(...) {
  }
}
```

This is not allowed in Java. You must declare them separately:

```
public static void main(...) {
  double randomValue = randomWithRange(...);
}

static double randomWithRange(...) {

}
```

Mind that you have to declare `randomWithRange` [`static`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413898/what-does-the-static-keyword-do-in-a-class) (as `main`) if you want to call it from your main method.